# Updating in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

If I update my app while it's in the review stage then will it take longer for my app to be seen?
I've looked all over I feel like and can't find an answer. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, a little longer than it would've taken for the current review to finish. I have done this previously but it's hard to tell the difference since app review times have been varying a lot due to ongoing pandemic. Btw, app review times are usually in order of 24 hours. Sometimes it can take upto 3-5 days.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know